# Is there a common method that returns number C that is closer to A from B by N?

Tags: .net, math

`Prev = 10, Cur = 17, Step = 2`.

Is there a method that will give me `Prev + Step` (or `Prev - Step` in case `Prev > Cur`)?

**UPD:** I'm looking for something like this:

```
int StepDifference(int A, int B, int N)
        {
            int ret;
            if (A > B)
                if (A - N >= B)
                    ret = A - N;
                else
                    ret = B;
            else
                if (A + N <= B)
                    ret = A + N;
                else
                    ret = B;
            return ret;
        }
```

Is there an "official" method in Math or other namespaces? I'm going to do this a lot and It could be slower with a custom implementation, I think. Almost every custom implementation of an "official" helper method I tried is slower, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: The question title isn't perfect. Feel free to make it more understandable.

Comment: I think Oracle has a patent on this function.

Comment: This sounds like a case of what-have-you-tried.  Is there a _method_ that can _return_, based on a _condition_, one of two _equations_.  Just plug in the missing elements.

Comment: @JasonOrendorff Accepted answerer has the right to sue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method in any Microsoft namespace.

Answer (score 3):

```
num = prev > cur ? prev - step : prev + step
```

Comment: I forgot code tags :-P. As far as a common function, I doubt there is, but it's really that simple.

Comment: If you're going to be doing it a lot then Oded's solution is probably cleaner. Out of curiosity...why?

Answer (score 2):

```
(Cur > Prev) ? Prev + Step : Prev - Step;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int Calculate(int Prev, int Cur, int Step)
{
  if(Prev > Cur)
    return Prev - Step;

  return Prev + Step
}
```

Comment: The naming of the function is not perfect. Feel free to make it more understandable.